# Are these limits correct? $\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{sup} \frac{\lambda (n)}{n}=1$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{inf} \frac{\lambda (n)}{n}=0$ exist?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf, totient-function, carmichael-function

I learned that from
[here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) for Euler totient function $\phi (n)$ , we have

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{sup} \frac{\phi (n)}{n}=1$$
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{inf} \frac{\phi (n)}{n}=0$$

However, I could not find such a limit for the Carmichael function $\lambda (n)$ which is associated with the Euler totient function. So I'm curious about the following limits:

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{sup} 
> \frac{\lambda (n)}{n}$$ and
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{inf} \frac{\lambda (n)}{n}$$

I think for any $n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ we have $\phi(n)≥\lambda(n)$. So, are the following limits correct?

> $\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{sup} 
> \frac{\lambda (n)}{n}=1$ and
> $\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{inf} \frac{\lambda (n)}{n}=0$

I could not find these limits.

Thank you.

Comment: The limsup for the totient is from the sequence of primes. The same holds with Carmichael function, because $\lambda(p)=\phi(p)=p-1$ for primes $p$. The liminf is due to $\lambda(n)\leq \phi(n)$, we have $\liminf (\lambda(n)/n )\leq \liminf (\phi(n)/n)$. This is from the sequence of primorials.

Comment: @i707107 thank you for comment. You mean $ \liminf (\lambda(n)/n )\leq \liminf (\phi(n)/n) \Rightarrow \liminf (\lambda(n)/n )=0 $ isn't it?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @i707107 Then, What can we say about $\limsup (\lambda(n)/n ) ?$

Comment: "What can we say about limsup(λ(n)/n)?" Did you read @i707107's first comment?

Comment: @Did $\lim\text{sup}_{p\to\infty}\frac{\lambda(p)}{p}=\lim\text{sup}_{p\to\infty}\frac{p-1}{p}=1$

Comment: @Did how can we show that $\lambda(p)=p-1?$. I know $\phi(p)$. Because, there exist a formula. But, I dont know formula for $\lambda(n)$. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm... Here is a suggestion: read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Comment: @Did Actually, before I asked this question, I read Carmichael in Wikipedia. But, I couldn't find the answer to my question there. Why, $\lambda(p)=p-1$

Comment: Huh? Quote: "Carmichael's theorem explains how to compute λ of a prime power: for a power of an odd prime and for 2 and 4, λ(n) is equal to the Euler totient φ(n)".

Comment: @Did then I also read Carmichael theorem, but I could not understand. The Quote doesn't show why $\lambda(p)=\phi(p)$

Comment: If your problem is, in the end, to understand a proof that $\lambda(p)=p-1$ for every prime number $p$, you might want to post a question asking this.

Comment: @Did I understood. $\lambda(n)$ is a discrete log isn't it?